# Ubuntu boot stuck on motherboard logo; Arch-based distro runs fine

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, uefi

Whenever I would boot into Ubuntu, it wouldn't boot and get stuck on the motherboard manufacturer logo. However, an arch-based distro like Manjaro booted completely fine.

Ubuntu Version: Kubuntu 21.10 
Mankaro version: 21.2.2 
Hardware: 
Motherboard: B450 Gaming-ITX/acc P3.40 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X 8-core 
GPU: NVIDIA Quadro M4000 
RAM: 8gb-3200mhz

Comment: @heynnema it is still stuck on the manufacture screen. no info, no logging, nothing, just the motherboard logo.

Comment: Do two things... try and boot to a Ubuntu Live USB and run it in "Try Ubuntu" mode, if you haven't already. Report back. In either case... enter the BIOS and find the option that sounds something like "reset to defaults" or "reset to factory" and try again. Report back.

Comment: @DementiaAswad Is your CPU or RAM overclocked? Also, please report back on my previous comment.

Comment: I added memtest to my answer.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Ubuntu display the manufacturer's BIOS splash screen during boot and shutdown. You need current versions of the BIOS.

**BIOS**

ASRock B450 Gaming-ITX/ac

You have an old BIOS version 3.40 from 7/25/2019. There's a newer BIOS available which may fix your problem... version 4.60 from 8/17/2021... and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/fatal1ty%20b450%20gaming-itxac/index.asp#BIOS).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**memtest**

AMD Ryzen 7 2700X 8-core

Ryzen processors are very fussy about memory.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

Updating the BIOS did not fix the problem. Added memtest.